# Mongodb querying for multiple parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've this collections

```
{
    "name" : "montalto",
    "users" : [
        {
            "username" : "ciccio",
            "email" : "aaaaaaaa",
            "password" : "aaaaaaaa",
            "money" : 0
        }
    ],
    "numers" : "8",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5040d3fded299bf03a000002")
}
```

If I want to search for a collection with the name of **montalto** and a user named **ciccio** I'm using the following query:

```
db.coll.find({name:'montalto', users:{username:'ciccio'}}).count()
```

But it does not work. Where I went wrong?

Comment: Ever heard of "embedded documents"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to match inside of embedded array objects:

```
db.coll.find({name: 'montalto', 'users.username': 'ciccio'}).count()
```

Comment: my code       `var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find({ "title": title, "author": author }).count();`...i just console this `cursor` variable..but it prints `[object promise]`.doesn't return the count of matched users..any suggestions?

Comment: @Jana Go ahead and post that as a new question.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify a **collection** is a group of **documents**. So your terminology in this question is slightly off.

To access embedded documents or objects you simply use dot notation as you would in traditional javascript.

```
db.coll.find({name: 'montalto', 'users.username': 'ciccio'})
```

You can of course add the `.count()`on the end of that.